# Distortion text in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to draw a .txt file like this in a tkinter window:

```
     ____________]
    |         |
    |         |
    |         |
              |
              |
              |
              |
              |
              |
              |
              |
              |
              |
              |
  (___________|__________)
```

I tried this code:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:

    g = Label(self.root,
        text=f.read(),
        background=self.BG,
        foreground=self.FG,
        font=self.FONT)

    g.pack()
    g.place(relx=0,rely=.06)
```

But my art was displayed with distortion. Spaces behave strangely:

[image]

I would be grateful for any help. Thanks!

Comment: Use a monospaced font instead, like `Consolas` or `TkFixedFont`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASCII art, as contained in your text file normally relies on monospace fonts, such as those used by default in most IDEs. If you change your `font=self.FONT` to `font='Courier'` as displayed below, Tkinter will use the font Courier. In Tkinter 8.0 and above, if the font Courier is not installed on the system, Tkinter will automatically use any monospace font. This is similar to CSS's

```
* {
    font-family: monospace;
}
```